# Angle between two vector

Tags: vectors

[image]

I tried to solve this by directly multiplies a-b and 6a+b equal zero, and substitute some of it with the |a| and |b| to get a.b. but somehow I get different answer from the answer sheet that is 60 degree

[image]

It is still not complete but after that I get some bizzare answer so I didn't write it

Comment: We can't say what the mistake was if we don't see your work. You can edit it into the question; use MathJax to make it readable: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Your method seems good (as far as one can tell from a rough verbal description) so maybe it's an arithmetic or sign error.

Comment: Your second last line should read, instead:
$$6(2)^{\color{red}{2}}-(3)^{\color{red}{2}}-\cdots$$

Comment: Okay, Its looks like I forgot to attach the square

Comment: Though not relevant to the computation of the dot product, you should also bear in mind that $a^2 + b^2 = 2^2$ and $r^2 + s^2 = 3^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $(\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b})\perp(6\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b})$, we know that
\begin{align}
(\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b})\cdot(6\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b})&=0\\
6\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{a}-5\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}-\overrightarrow{b}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}&=0\\
6|\overrightarrow{a}|^2-5\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}-|\overrightarrow{b}|^2&=0\\
6(2)^2-5\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}-(3)^2&=0\\
-5\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}&=-15\\
\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}&=3
\end{align}

From the definition of the dot product:
\begin{align}
\cos\theta&=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{b}}{|\overrightarrow{a}||\overrightarrow{b}|}\\
\cos\theta&=\dfrac{3}{(2)(3)}\\
\cos\theta&=\dfrac12\\
\theta&=60^{\circ}
\end{align}

Anything from here that needs further explanation?

Comment: Oh, so we can treat vector multiplication the same as algebraic multiplication?

Comment: Very much so -- after all, $\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}$, etc. are vectors in algebraic form.